# Android TV app's payment

Tags: android, paypal, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-tv

I am building Android TV app, which can watch videos in the app.

My videos are paid, user needs to pay in order to watch.

Is it possible to do the payment in Android TV app?

Is it possible to use In-App-Billing if the TV has Google Play service

Is it possible to use third-party payment gateways, like Paypal or Cybersource if the TV does not have Google Play service.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do the payment in Android TV app?

Yes, app should comply with [these](https://play.google.com/about/monetization-ads/payments/) guidelines. Paid videos within app qualify for IAP.

> Is it possible to use In-App-Billing if the TV has Google Play service

Yes

> Is it possible to use third-party payment gateways, like Paypal or Cybersource if the TV does not have Google Play service.

If you're targeting firetv, you need to fulfil payments using Amazon AppStore using Amazon IAP which has a slightly different implementation than Android IAP. More details [here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/docs-v2/understanding-in-app-purchasing).

Comment: as I recall, if you distribute your app on Google Play, all in-app purchases must be done using Google In-App billing, using PayPal could (and probably will) result on the app being suspended.